# Grep for a pattern with white space

Tags: grep

I have a text file with content

```
pattern(  
pattern  ( 
PATTERN  (
```

How to write a grep statement if there are any number of spaces between the pattern and (.

```
grep - ir "pattern (" textfile
```

This will search for only pattern followed one whitespace and (

Comment: You can use this instead to match 0 or more spaces: `grep - ir "pattern\s*(" textfile`

Comment: It doesnt work. It gives only first pattern

Comment: This is a bit broad. Try to give a [mcve].

Comment: What version of grep are you using? And try `grep -i "pattern[[:space:]]*(" textfile` as I believe some versions of grep don't handle `\s` correctly